# Merge branch, but with one modified commit

Tags: git, merge, branch, branching-and-merging

I have a git branch from a collaborator that I would like to merge. The problem is that there is a mistake in one of the early commits (for example the commit message must be changed or some EOL chars must be fixed).

It would take me 2 minutes to fix that problem if I cherry-picked the commits in a local branch and then did an interactive rebase + edit.

The problem is that if I do that, then the original branch from the collaborator will no longer be seen as merged by various tools, GitHub firstly.

**Is there a workflow that allows me to merge the branch with the fixes and still see the original branch as merged?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve your collaborator's original branch, do your cherry-pick+rebase then `git merge -s ours badbranch` with a "correct bad whitespace" message and then if you're not already on your master branch merge to that normally.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workflow to merge branches that need small fixes, adapted from the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23832526/449288).

The branch we want to merge is `collaborator/fix-bug-10`.

First, we set up a local branch and cherry-pick all the commits in the collaborator's branch.

```
git checkout master
git branch collaborator-fix-bug-10 # hyphen instead of slash
git checkout collaborator-fix-bug-10
git cherry-pick COMMIT1
git cherry-pick COMMIT2
git cherry-pick COMMIT2
```

Then we fix the problems.

```
git rebase -i master # show commits between HEAD and master
# fix problems
git rebase --continue
```

After that we "merge" the collaborator's branch with our branch. This is the gist of the accepted solution.

```
git merge --strategy ours collaborator/fix-bug-10
```

Last we merge our local branch into our master branch.

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only collaborator-fix-bug-10
git branch --delete collaborator-fix-bug-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does cherry-pick enter into it? Do the interactive rebase on the original branch, edit the commit message, and then merge the branch as normal.